# How to force UICollectionView with fewer items to scroll?

Tags: ios6, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I am working with a UICollectionView that displays fewer items than necessary to fill the whole screen.
With this setting, the view simply does not scroll (move and bounce), when I add like 20 items it works.

**How can I force the collection view to scroll, without enough items to fill the screen?**

[image]
<sub>(source: [bytolution.com](http://bytolution.com/Screenshot%202013.04.17%2021.57.00.png))</sub>

Thanks for your help!

*BTW I already tried to set the contentSize (e.g. to {320 , 1000}) but it still does not work.*

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try to set `alwaysBounceVertical` property to `YES`:

```
self.collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
```

The default value is `NO`

Comment: Also seen as `Bounce Vertically` in the right Interface Builder menu under `Attributes Inspector` when the collectionView is selected in IB. (The middle option with the downward arrow)