# Make the UICollectionView scrollable even when its not full

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

The UICollectionView disables scrolling by default when there is not enough cells in the view. When this occurs I need it to bounce back to position when pulled. Im am aware of a hack where I can fill the UICollectionView with empty tables to enable scrolling but I was hoping there would be a slightly more fluid example as

I don't want the view to scroll but instead to automatically bounce back to its position. This is because of the effect I have implemented below as can see below.

https://youtu.be/r75xB9-Mb4g

Is there a way to achieve this simply, when there is not enough cells in the UICollectionView the scroll is disabled.

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079624/how-to-force-uicollectionview-with-fewer-items-to-scroll

Comment: That was not scroll view . is it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For vertical scrolling:

```
self.collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true;
```

For horizontal scrolling:

```
self.collectionView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = true;
```