# Make uiCollectionView scrollable when not full

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview

I want my CollectionView to still be able to scroll a bit up and down when there’s only a few cells (to get that bounce effect). In a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253476/make-the-uicollectionview-scrollable-even-when-its-not-full) it was suggested that using

```
self.collectionview?.alwaysBounceVerticle = true
```

would work (this was marked as the correct answer) but this doesn’t work anymore.

I’m using swift 3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After looking tying some stuff in the interface builder it turns out that you have to check the box for “Bounces” **and** “Bounces Vertically”

Answer (score 5):

You can configure it using Storyboard.
Just select your collection view and in attribute inspector check * Bounces* and *Bounce Vertically*.

[image]

Comment: Yeah I just saw I had that box checked but didn’t have the box for “Bounces” checked. So it only bounced when there was lots of cells

Answer (score 5):

```
// swift
self.collectionview?.alwaysBounceVertical = true
self.collectionview?.bounces = true
```