# Force UICollectionView to scroll until a specific cell is centered

Tags: ios, objective-c, scroll, uicollectionview

First of all, I already read [How to force UICollectionView with fewer items to scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079624/how-to-force-uicollectionview-with-fewer-items-to-scroll) and it did not solve my problem.

I have an horizontal UICollectionView with 5 cells, and only 5 cells are needed to fill the screen width. This means the 3rd cell is centered. How can I scroll so the 4th cell is centered?

When using `scrollToItemAtIndexPath`, it won't scroll since there is not enough cells to scroll. In other words, if I want my 4th cell to be centered, there would be a blank space at the end since I only have 5 cells (and vice-versa for the 2nd cell).

Is adding empty cells the only solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could adjust the insets on the collection view.  Add enough space that you can center the last cell.

More info from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/UsingtheFlowLayout/UsingtheFlowLayout.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH3-SW7)